# Как построить график зависимости даты от числа из одной колонки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть файл примерно с таким содержанием:

```
56  2016-11-18
4   2016-11-19
4   2016-11-20
244 2016-11-21
280 2016-11-22
```

Я хочу построить график, который будет показывать зависимость даты от числа из первой колонки.

Не могу понять как работать с датой в графиках.

Comment: Как на счет использования модуля Pandas? Вы хотите построить график с датами на оси X и значениями (числами) на оси Y - я правильно вас понял?

Comment: @MaxU да, вы правильно поняли

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Предположим, что данные находятся в файле: `D:\temp\.data\594897.csv`

Вот решение, использующее [Pandas модуль](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

fn = r'D:\temp\.data\594897.csv'
# читаем CSV/TXT файл (разделённый пробелами) в DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(fn, sep='\s+', header=None, names=['Value','Date'], parse_dates=['Date'])
# рисуем график
df.plot(x='Date', y='Value', rot=0, figsize=(14, 10), grid=True, marker='o')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPDATE: рисуем график с первого числа месяца:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *

# добавим в DF строку с первым числом месяца
df.loc[len(df)] = [np.nan, df.Date.min() - MonthBegin(1)]
# устанавливаем `Date` в качестве индекса и отсортируем индекс
df = df.set_index('Date').sort_index()

df.plot(figsize=(14, 10), grid=True, marker='o')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @jfs, я не совсем понял, что вы имеете в виду - куда подвинуть?...

Comment: @jfs к сожалению, никак не могу научиться грамотно задавать вопросы. Под первым числом я имел ввиду число в первой колонке таблицы из файла. Мой косяк... Поправил в вопросе.

Comment: @jfs, автору это не нужно, но я добавил в ответ - вдруг кому-то пригодится...

Comment: А можно ли сделать такой график интерактивным ? Приближать там некоторые области и все такое...

Comment: @faoxis, можно, используя [plot.ly](https://plot.ly/) или [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#wheelzoomtool)

Answer (score 3):

Вот пример кода, использующий только Matplotlib. Считаем, что даты уже преобразованы к date.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from datetime import date

import pylab
import matplotlib.dates


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Даты, которые будут отложены по оси X
    xdata = [date(2010, 5, 25),
             date(2010, 7, 5),
             date(2010, 12, 1),
             date(2011, 3, 17),
             date(2011, 8, 2),
             date(2011, 11, 13),
             date(2012, 3, 15),
             date(2012, 4, 8),
             date(2012, 12, 21)
             ]

    # Данные, которые будут отложены по оси Y
    ydata = [0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.6, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0]

    # Преобразуем даты в числовой формат
    xdata_float = matplotlib.dates.date2num(xdata)

    # Вызовем subplot явно, чтобы получить экземпляр класса AxesSubplot,
    # из которого будем иметь доступ к осям
    axes = pylab.subplot(1, 1, 1)

    # Пусть в качестве меток по оси X выводится только год
    axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%Y"))

    # Отобразим данные
    pylab.plot_date(xdata_float, ydata, fmt="b-")

    # Изменим левую границу
    pylab.xlim(xmin=matplotlib.dates.date2num(date(2010, 5, 1)))

    pylab.grid()
    pylab.show()
```

Более подробно про работу с датами в Matplotlib можете почитать здесь - http://jenyay.net/Matplotlib/Date